# Iphone 4 MFmailcompose viewcontroller crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
     Iphone 4 MFMailComposeViewController 



     MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Welcome" isHTML:NO];
    [controller release];

  My app to be crash.
  Wat i  did wrong
```

Regards,
Arun

Comment: What error prints in console?

Comment: Firstly, format your question properly... Secondly, your code does nothing.. Why would you create and release something right away. If you are sure the problem is in this piece of code, you might as well comment out this entire snippet. Its not doing anything anyways...

Comment: Just take a tutorial sample code for making a mail app, which you can find with google, or take a demo code from apple. there is enough out in the web which works and you have just to modify it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arun , First up all configure the email settings in your device

Answer (score 2):

The mail composer will crash if the user is unable to send mail. First check to see if the user is able to send mail before trying to instantiate a MFMailComposeViewController.

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
   MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Akira says, you can use MFMailComposeViewController after you set up the device's e-mail settings.

Answer (score -1):

init failed, because not iOS mail-application's setting.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if (!controller) // failed
    return; // auto view alert, "not mail setting..."
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```